# node and reactjs axios server request returning index.html file instead of json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, axios

I have setup my project with a react frontend being compiled by webpack and the server running on node and express.

When I deploy to production my requests to the server are returning the index.html file in the 'dist' folder rather than the json with the data.

My webpack compiled output is at the location ./dist.

Here is the routing part of my server.js file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('dist'));
  const path = require('path');
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
  });
}
// Use our router configuration when we call /
app.use('/', router);
```

Here is part of my webpack config file:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './client/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './dist',
    port: 8080,
    proxy: { '/api/**': { target: 'http://localhost:3000', secure: false } }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader', query: {presets: ['es2015','react'], plugins: ['transform-es2015-destructuring', 'transform-object-rest-spread']}},
        {test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.svg$|\.png$/i, loader: 'file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]'},
        {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader','resolve-url-loader']},
        {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader','postcss-loader', 'sass-loader','resolve-url-loader']}
        ]
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

My request is as follows (the api route /api/chefs returns a json with user profiles (tested in development):

```
export function listChefs() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.get('/api/chefs')
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: LIST_CHEFS,
          payload: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        errorHandler(dispatch, 'There was a problem. Please refresh and try again.');
      });
  };
}
```

It seems as though the call that I am making from my client using axios is actually hitting the api url that isn't being recognised and therefore is being redirected to simply server the index.html file.

Any help?

Cheers

Comment: What does the axios request look like?

Comment: I've updated the question with the axios request

Comment: Do you have an endpoint defined in express to handle this route?

Comment: Yes the endpoint api/chefs is in my chefs routes and handles this endpoint

Answer (score 2):

perhaps this is the offending line:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

becuase this catches all your requests. If you change `/*` to `/` does that fix it?

I think the request can't make it to your router because `/*` catches all requests and returns the index.html page.

try:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Intially I was using the former code snippet here but it hasn't made a difference. I will update the code on the question to use the correct syntax.

Comment: After 7 hours of futile debugging, this did it for me !
Make sure you delete your "public" folder from the app before attempting this fix, otherwise, you'll keep getting redirected to the index.html inside the public folder (unless you explicitly configure the app otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/), you can specify the proxy setting as follows

```
proxy: {
  "/api": {
    target: "https://other-server.example.com",
    secure: false
  }
}
```

Notice the "/api" rather than "/api/**".

Also, it may be worth noting that they recommend using absolute paths via `path.join(__dirname, "dist")` for the contentBase setting.